# lightning web component not visible in app builder or home page or record page

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am facing an issue where i am using vscode and deployed a lightning component to my org but i am unable to  see the component in my app page or record page.

deployed component

[image: Component not visible]
Metadata.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Product Card</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <objects>
                <object>Product__c</object>
            </objects>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Have you enabled my domain in this org? Custom components will only be visible in a domain enabled org